# How to find out when a downloaded with nsIWebBrowserPersist is finished? (Firefox 30, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, download, firefox-addon, status, http-status-codes

When in "onStateChange" I check for (thisRequestStatus == 200) this seems not only to be triggered when the image is finished downloading, but twice or more often in the course of downloading one URL. (The text in infoElementCurrentURL runs down much too early to the last URL.)

I only want that code to be trigged once, so it only downloads 1 image at a time, and not two or much more simultaneously. (I have a much longer URL list, though here I only put in 5 URL.)

**How to find out when a downloaded with nsIWebBrowserPersist is finished?**

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm");
const WebBrowserPersist = Components
    .Constructor("@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1",
                                                 "nsIWebBrowserPersist");
var progressElement = cd.getElementById("id:sp:downloadProgressInfo");
var infoElementCurrentURL = cd.getElementById("id:sp:downloadInfoCurrentURL");
var urlArrayFinal = ["https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3745/13112412145_590436f5f0_o.jpg"
,"https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3799/13112697234_fe0db6aa59_o.jpg"
,"https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2870/13112697464_c401657ec1_o.jpg"
,"https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7005/6582177439_8777d33c95_o.jpg"
,"https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7025/6582206291_853b99e6dc_o.jpg"
,"https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7148/6582203143_d7d627f95a_o.jpg"];
function downloadImage(theURL) {
    infoElementCurrentURL.innerHTML = '' + urlArrayFinal.length + ': ' + theURL;
    var persist = WebBrowserPersist();
    var targetFilePathName = "C:\\\\zttest\\"+theURL.substr(theURL.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    var obj_URI = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService)
        .newURI(theURL, null, null);
    var targetFile = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    targetFile.initWithPath(targetFilePathName);
    if(!targetFile.exists()) {
      targetFile.create(0x00,0644);
    }
    var privacy = null;
    persist.progressListener = {
      onProgressChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aCurSelfProgress, aMaxSelfProgress, aCurTotalProgress, aMaxTotalProgress) {
        var percentComplete = Math.round((aCurTotalProgress / aMaxTotalProgress) * 100);
        progressElement.textContent = '' + percentComplete +"%";
      },
      onStateChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aStateFlags, aStatus) {
        try {var httpChannel = aRequest.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
          var thisRequestStatus = httpChannel.responseStatus;
          var thisRequestLength = httpChannel.getResponseHeader("Content-Length");
        } catch(ex) {
        }
        if (thisRequestStatus == 200) {
            progressElement.textContent = thisRequestStatus;
            if (urlArrayFinal.length>0) { window.setTimeout(downloadImage(urlArrayFinal.pop(), 100)); }
        }
      }
    }
    persist.saveURI(obj_URI, null, null, null, "", targetFile, privacy);
}

if (urlArrayFinal.length>0) { downloadImage(urlArrayFinal.pop()); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onStateChange` is the way to go, however you'll need to check that `aStateFlags` is actually [`Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_STOP`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWebProgressListener#State_Transition_Flags).

So, something along the lines of the following will do the trick:

```
onStateChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aStateFlags, aStatus) {
  if (!(aStateFlags & Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_STOP)) {
    // Not done yet
    return;
  }
  if (urlArrayFinal.length>0) {
    setTimeout(downloadImage(urlArrayFinal.pop(), 100));
  }
}
```

Please note that checking whether it is a HTTP 200 response is not sufficient, nor correct in your logic. E.g. when you received a 404, downloading would stop without loading other images.

Comment: Hi!
onStateChange is called twice. The aStateFlag value is
first 327681, then 327696.

I now replaced Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_STOP with 327696. It works nice. But of course it's not really a save thing to do it this way. Should I make a bit comparison, like 

`if (aStateFlags & Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_STOP)`

Comment: Eek. Seems I wasn't paying attention when initially posting. Of course you'll have to a bit-or. Answer corrected.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now. I already read about all those states before, but I interpreted the mozilla help files differently, so I wouldn't have tried this myself. Happily this was the last thing I had to do and now I could call my project to be on version 1. :)